# JSSOR slider window resize memory leaks

Tags: jquery, memory

Experiencing memory leaks with my JSSOR slider implementation when the browser window is resized. Any solution.

```
var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);
//responsive code begin
//you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
function ScaleSlider() {
    var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
    if (parentWidth)
        jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.max(Math.min(parentWidth, 800), 300));
    else
        window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
}

ScaleSlider();

if (!navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|BlackBerry|IEMobile)/)) {
    $(window).bind('resize', ScaleSlider);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow (SO). Please read [ask]

Comment: It creates nothing while resize. Let me check it out anyway. What's your device/browser/version which leads memory leak?